# Should I be concerned about moisture around sprinkler head and vent grates in my bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, moisture

I recently moved into a mid-rise condo with a bathroom situated in the interior of the building (no windows). The bathroom has relatively poor ventilation--there's no exhaust fan and it has just a single small vent.

I noticed that, after taking a shower, there's a noticeable accumulation of moisture around the sprinkler head in the ceiling:

[image: spinkler head with moisture visible in the surrounding paint]

This appears pretty rapidly after starting to take a shower (within a couple minutes). For longer showers (or multiple showers taken back-to-back), similar moisture appears around the vent grate in the ceiling. Leaving the door open doesn't seem to help much, although I have not tested this extensively.

Is this something to be concerned about? If so, is there any way to address it? My condo association prohibits adding an exhaust fan to the bathroom, although they say they are evaluating ways to improve the ventilation of the building more generally.

Comment: It looks like a cold surface, e.g., sprinkler pipe and mounting plate, are causing condensation from shower water vapor. Yes, I would be concerned, since plaster degrades when continually wet. You might need legal assistance in writing a *letter* to the association, to make clear you've informed them of the issue and to reduce your liability should damage occur.

Comment: Is there a unit above you, or are you on the top floor of the building?

Comment: I'm pretty sure code requires either an operable window or an exhaust fan in every  bathroom. Jurisdiction?

Comment: My unit is in the middle of the building (7th floor out of 13).

I believe the lack of exhaust fan is indeed a code violation in my city.  The association believes there's supposed to be some kind of centralized exhaust fan for the building but it's either inoperable or was never installed.  They're considering filing a complaint against the builder, although I don't know if this will make a difference considering the building is about 15 years old now.